# Allow high rep users to 'suggest edits' rather than have them automatically accepted

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After a certain point user's edits don't need approval, and automatically go through.

I'd like to, at time, suggest an edit to the OP that might not be what they are after. Yes they can rollback anyway, but it would prevent questions being edited more than they need to, and give less work for the OP, instead of rolling back and editing their rewording.

In that time, instead of being edited twice it's brought back up to the main page twice, potentially when only once is required, especially if the editor misinterpreted the oririnal intent, and this could remain on the edit history.

I ask because I ran into this situation with my edit [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/11080/revisions).

Is this suggestion worth implementing?

Comment: Why won't a comment do in that case?

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to articulate in an edit, or the context of the post needs to be included for the edit to make sense.

Comment: I can't say I've ever seen a situation where I imagine a suggested edit would be a fitting action. When in doubt: don't edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not a needed feature.

If you aren't sure about if your edit improves the question simply do not edit the post. Or edit the parts that you know for sure that you can improve, and leave the unclear parts alone. Leave a comment to the OP, asking *him/her* to clarify what you don't understand. Why even try to improve something that you don't fully understand, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Agreed, and also for suggested edits. Those are not intended to "propose" edits one is not certain about either.